# Problems mocking out Repository with Moq

Tags: c#-4.0, moq, repository-pattern

I am trying to mock out my Repository with Moq.  I am trying to mock out all the query methods on my Repository.  I have been successful in mocking out the method to return all of  for the type I have mocked out.

Example:

```
mockProductRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(products.AsQueryable());
```

However, I am having a problem mocking out a method that utilizes another method.  For example, my "FilterBy" method returns a call to my "GetAll" method with a Where Clause that takes an expression

**Example: Repository Method**

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
   return GetAll().Where(expression);
}
```

The kicker is that I was hoping to mock out all the methods on the repository in a helper class:

```
public static IRepository<Product> MockProductRepository(params Product[] products) {
        var mockProductRepo = new Mock<IRepository<Product>>();
        mockProductRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(products.AsQueryable());
        mockProductRepo.Setup(x => x.FilterBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>())).Returns(products.AsQueryable().Where(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>()));
        return mockProductRepo.Object;
}
```

So instead of the FilterBy method mocked out above, is there a way to set it up to call on another mocked out method instead of the way I have it in the above example?

**UPDATE**

I have tried the setup:

```
mockProductRepo.Setup(x => x.FilterBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>())).Returns(mockProductRepo.Object.GetAll().Where(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>()));
```

And it always errors that "Value cannot be null.  Parameter: predicate".  From what I understand of the stack trace it is complaining because I am not passing "Where" a predicate.  I am not sure how in the setup to denote the expression passed into the FilterBy method to be used in the filter Where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it myself.

```
mockProductRepo.Setup(x => x.FilterBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>())).Returns((Expression<Func<Product,bool>> filter) => mockProductRepo.Object.GetAll().Where(filter));
```